# When typeof is run on a function, it returns "function" as the type. Why doesn't it return "object"?

Tags: javascript, typeof

A function in Javascript is an object.

When running typeof on a function, why does it return the value "function", instead of "object"?

```js
var objLit = {}
console.log(typeof objLit); // "object"

function hello() {
  console.log("hello world");
}
console.log(typeof hello); // "function"
```

Comment: [Because the spec says so.](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator)

Comment: hum because `hello` is a function, not an `Object`

Comment: Simon, `hello` is an an object.[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#targetText=Like%20the%20program%20itself%2C%20a,just%20like%20any%20other%20object.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's what the specification says to do. Although all functions are objects, when using `typeof` on a function will return `'function'` instead of `'object'`. See the [table](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-35):

```
Type of val                            Result:
Object (does not implement [[Call]])   "object"
Object (implements [[Call]])           "function"
```

(Functions have the internal method [[Call]]; non-functions do not.)

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks. So if it's an object that uses a call (aka, a function), typeof will return "function" as the value.  If it's an object that does NOT implement a call, it will return "object" as the value.